# JBoss EAP 7 with Oracle Datasource

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I am trying to access an Oracle DB connection using Jboss datasource but it's throwing java.lang.NullPointerException.

Below is my code and jboss shows below logs during startup.
What's wrong in my code?

```
 WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/testOracleDS]




@WebServlet("/Index")
public class Index extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DataSource dataSource;
    Connection conn = null;

    public Index() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException {

        try {
            DataSource anotherDataSource = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/jdbc/testOracleDS");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            System.out.println("connection established");
            response.getWriter().println("connection established");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.getWriter().println("failed to establish connection: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `dataSource` is `null`. You're initializing (and throwing away) `anotherDataSource` in your init method.

Comment: @Kayaman, thanks can you please provide your answer for code changes to be done

Comment: Uh, replace `DataSource anotherDataSource` with just `dataSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adjusting code, The Datasource variable was not correctly initialized

public class Index extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
private DataSource dataSource;
Connection conn = null;

public Index() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void init() throws ServletException {

    try {
       dataSource = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/jdbc/testOracleDS");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection established");
        response.getWriter().println("connection established");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.getWriter().println("failed to establish connection: " + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```